# Retrieve a message box when double clicking a cell

Tags: vba, excel, double-click

I have a file in which I want to define a couple of ranges, store them in an array and apply some modifications to specific groups inside that array (or in the whole array as well).
Everything in the code below runs smoothly (even if there might be some unnecessary declarations, but that's my fault); but I wanted to add, inside the "Select Case" for the first three months of the year,
some lines of code which would allow to somehow "protect" the cells, pretty much as follows:

"If (**need code for this**): double-click or press F2 in any given cell of the defined array (with the intention of inserting information in that cell) Then

MsgBox "You can't add information manually on this specific cell"

End If"

The idea is to create afterwards some buttons which will open up Insert boxes - and the values inserted in those boxes will be subsequently registered in the cells, never allowing "manual" writing.

If someone could help me with this, I would be grateful! Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Structure4()

Application.Workbooks("Book1").Activate

Dim arr As Variant
arr = Array("A6:C105", "I6:AM105", "AN6:AN105", "AO6:AO105", "AP6:AP105", "AQ6:AQ105", "AR6:AR105", "AS6:AS105", "AT6:AT105", "AU6:AU105", "AV6:AV105", "AW6:AW105", "AX6:AX105", "AY6:AY105", "AZ6:AZ105", "BA6:BA105", "BB6:BB105", "BC6:BG105", "BH6:BH105", "BI6:BL105")

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Book1")

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    Select Case ws.name
    Case "January", "February", "March"
        With ws
            ws.Select
            For i = 0 To 19
                With .Range(arr(i))
                    .Font.name = "Arial Unicode MS"
                    .Font.Size = 8
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                End With
                Select Case i
                    Case 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17
                        .Range(arr(i)).NumberFormat = "0.0;[Red]0.0"
                End Select
            Next
        End With
    End Select
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just protect those cells, using `Worksheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True` - then users can't manually edit the protected cells, but your code can.

Comment: Yep, it's far more simple than my fairy tail... :) But then again, I aint' got informatic background, so I'm unaware of a lot of these possibilities... And yours serves perfectly for the purpose, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

place the following code in your worksheet code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Dim rng As Range
Dim val As Variant
Dim arrRng As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(arrRng, Target) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You can't add information manually on this specific cell"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(arrRng, Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Address = rng.Address Then
            If Target.Value <> val Then
                MsgBox "You can't add information manually on this specific cell"
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Value = val
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set arrRng = Range("A6:C105, I6:AM105, AN6:AN105, AO6:AO105, AP6:AP105, AQ6:AQ105, AR6:AR105, AS6:AS105, AT6:AT105, AU6:AU105, AV6:AV105, AW6:AW105, AX6:AX105, AY6:AY105, AZ6:AZ105, BA6:BA105, BB6:BB105, BC6:BG105, BH6:BH105, BI6:BL105")

    If Not Intersect(arrRng, Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Count = 1 Then
            Set rng = Target
            val = Target.Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @FábioEspadaneira, any feedback?